# DIY or Custom Quadcopter

Tags: quadcopters, long-range-drone, diy

I want a quadcopter with (2)lb payload capacity, (5)mi range, 30mph min. speed, long-range fpv, waypoints, & ZERO enforced geofencing. I am willing to use/accept any combination of hardware/software as long as above specs are met. Can anyone suggest a specific product, build a setup meeting the requirements for me for around $1,500, or point me to someone who will, or suggest a product that can be modified to these requirements?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are dropping some cell phones in prison fences.

I will hit these point by point:

**2lb capacity:** Anything 5"+ can do it.

**5mi range:**

You will need a BVLoS waiver to be legal. Good luck; they run about \$20k in legal fees last time I looked. Of course, that will also need a commercial license. Not gonna lie; a legal BVLoS flight is pretty much impossible.

Digital FPV will cover you but can be sketchy at a distance. Many factors, such as geography, quality of gear, and EM noise floor.  5 miles is a big ask and most commonly seen away from urban areas (less EM noise).

**No geofencing:** Build your own

No such specific OTS product exists. SkyDio is close, but they are just Chinese crap (they assemble in the USA).  Also big \$.

**\$1500 budget**-- good luck - some round numbers:  Digital goggles w/upgrades $800, Underlying custom drone \$500, \$100 release mechanism, \$200 transmitter. \$250 batteries and charger (to start), \$100 charger, \$500 flight controller and GPS gear (minimum), FPV transmitter + antenna \$100.  Closer to \$3k to start.